# ¿Cómo llamo una función y envió datos a esa funcion?

Tags: vb.net

¿Cómo puedo enviar por parámetro a otra clase en vb.net? Es que yo conozco java pero veo que no obviamente no es ni parecido.

En Java seria así:

```
private void btnIniciarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{ 

        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setNombreUsuario(txtUsername.getText());
        user.setClave(txtPassword.getText());
        validar = Gestor.validarLogin(user.getNombreUsuario(),user.getClave());

}
```

Me pueden enseñar una forma de llamar una función y enviar por parámetro a esa función para vb.net.

Por aquello lo que quiero es utilizar una capa lógica

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y publica un ejemplo en java de lo que quieres hacer vb.net

Comment: Java no es tan diferente la verdad. Como dice @Einer, pon un ejemplo de lo que intentas conseguir

Comment: Y ahora?? Yo lo que quiero es como la linea donde dice: 

Gestor.validarLogin(user.getNombreUsuario(),user.getClave());

Answer (score 0):

En teoría, metiendo esto en el evento de click, funcionaría.

Dim para crear la variable `user` usas `As` para definir el tipo de objeto, en este caso, `Usuario`, es la única diferencia, lo del evento, en visual studio te lo añade de forma automatica.

```
        Dim user As Usuario  = new Usuario();
        user.setNombreUsuario(txtUsername.getText());
        user.setClave(txtPassword.getText());
        validar = Gestor.validarLogin(user.getNombreUsuario(),user.getClave());
```

No sé si es esto a lo que te referías.

Comment: Yo me refería al llamado y envio de datos a otra clase, Gestor.validarLogin(user.getNombreUsuario(),user.getClave());

No me funciona, mi código seria: 

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

        Dim usuario As String = txtUsername.Text
        Dim clave As String = txtPassword.Text

        CapaLogica.Login(usuario, clave)
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

.
.
- @AritzBello

Comment: Por qué no haces una variable local privada, con metodo get, usando en vez de ByVal, ByRef es decir. Private Usuario  Private Contraseña private Sub getUsuario(parametros), private Sub getContraseña(); No sé si me he explicado.

Comment: Ya lo logré, lo que quería era esto:

            Dim CL As New CapaLogica()
            aceptar = CL.Login(usuario, clave)

Answer (score 0):

La manera que quería era esta, la solución era simple:

```
        Dim CL As New CapaLogica()
        aceptar = CL.Login(usuario, clave)
```

Ese pequeño código llama a otra función de una clase aparte, la ejecuta y envía valores. Solo me hacia falta el New a la hora de declarar.